# Docker container does not start on executing docker run command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created a dockerfile for starting kafka in standalone mode. Docker build is working fine. On executing docker command
 `docker run -p 9092:9092 -p 2181:2181 <imageID>`
I see that the container is not started. But there are no errors while execution. I tried to capture the logs using `docker events&` and could see the following

```
2016-02-11T04:28:44.012268995-05:00 842b99f89a846431bf1661dd40b635558a5e859727ca6953c95e323a8d221409: (from cb196b74879a) create
842b99f89a846431bf1661dd40b635558a5e859727ca6953c95e323a8d221409
2016-02-11T04:28:44.845660927-05:00 842b99f89a846431bf1661dd40b635558a5e859727ca6953c95e323a8d221409: (from cb196b74879a) start
2016-02-11T04:28:45.053143162-05:00 842b99f89a846431bf1661dd40b635558a5e859727ca6953c95e323a8d221409: (from cb196b74879a) die
```

I tried to open the terminal to the container using the image ID and tried to start kafka server in commandline and it is working as expected. I am not sure of the issue here. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried `docker logs -f <CONTAINER_ID>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a docker container will exit if the process on which it hangs exits.
For example

```
CMD ./myscript.sh
```

will exit when the script exits BUT

```
CMD tail -f myfile
```

will not exit because the tail -f command does not exit

If you need to keep an exiting container alive then try

```
docker run -dti
```

or

```
docker run -dt
```

Comment: Yes you are right. one of the shell script CMDs in my dockerfile had issues because of which the container exited. Thanks a lot :)